# How long will a 10 second youtube intro take to render? I have had it rendering for hours upon hours and it all seems too much!

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am not asking for a solution to speed it up, i simply want to know how long it should take!

I would also like a way to speed it up but not something technical, im new to Blender!

Comment: It depends _a lot_ on the scene you're rendering and your hardware, therefore, it's off-topic.

Comment: It's impossible to give an estimate. It all depends on your system. Render one frame and multiply that by the number of frames you need to get an idea of how long it takes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on the scene.  As a starting point, I would recommend rendering one frame and see how long that takes.  If your animation is 10 seconds and you are rendering at 24 frames per second then your whole animation will be 240 frames.  If it takes one hour per frame then your whole animation will take 240 hours or 10 days.  Of course, I'm assuming a lot without knowing about your scene.

The actual time it takes could vary greatly from my estimate.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot say how long it should take since that depends on what you are rendering. It could be a minute, it could be a month. However, it is possible to give a rough estimate of how much longer you have to wait for your animation to finish. Wait for a frame to finish, and look in the upper left corner to see how long it took.

[image]

Multiply this number by the amount of frames that are left to render and you know how much longer you have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

**It is impossible to give an estimate of how long rendering will take**..

Rendering time depends on:

**1** The kind of hardware you are using (brand and type of CPU, speed of CPU, number of cores/threads, amount of RAM available, kind of GPU, number of cuda cores and vRAM available, speed of the hard drives, etc.)

**2** The complexity of the scene. Complex scenes will take more time to render than simpler ones depending of the number of vertices, subdivisions, instances, size of textures, complexity of physics or particle simulations, use of volumetric effects, motion blur, number of samples, compositing effects, etc.

Rendering the same scene an old computer with a single core can take hours while it can be a just few minutes on a modern multi CPU/multicore computer.